# Unable to submit archive including Here Maps Premium SDK with Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, here-api, xcode8.2

[archive upload failure messages screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWLrB.jpg)

Xcode was failing to submit a project including dynamic library "NMAKit.framework" required for Here Map Premium for iOS functionality.

(uploading the sample project included in Here Maps Premium SDK for iOS to avoid side effects caused by my project leading also to upload failure)

Bitcode was disabled in project's build settings.

I'am using the latest Xcode Version 8.2.1.

I don't have trouble submitting the app without NMAKit.framework.

It seems like the actual version (Here SDK V. 3.3) of the library is not accepted by Apple.

What steps would it take to get my project including the NMAKit.framework submitted to iTunes-Connect?

Comment: Are you using the Starter of Premium version of the HERE SDK?

Comment: Premium version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Project->Target->Build Phase->Run Script

Add Run Script

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

you can follow this [Link](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/).

**Step 2:**

Project->Target->General->Embedded Binaries

Add NMAKit.framework like below image

[image]

Comment: it is not working, I followed to instruction. no luck

Comment: maybe because I also have fabric script there.

Comment: yes, I found the issue, it is because I already had script related to fabric
and I combined to scripts together. I figured out that I need to create separate run script for different scripts.

Comment: @YestayMuratov it is use to different scripts.add fabric and add NMAKit Run scripts.

Comment: @HimanshuPatel Finally I could not submit ipa to app store, and run script which is downloaded with framework, and located inside of framework. The script that is provided in answer works because when I add it I cant run on simulator, but still cant upload to app store. that is why I decided to run script which is provided inside of framework.

Comment: @YestayMuratov i have Safety Cam GPS Project in used here-map sdk Live on app store. Already working this points share this projects (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/safety-cam-gps/id1177370285?mt=8) Any have issue drop this email address himanshubutani10@gmail.com

Comment: @HimanshuPatel this scrip was perfect working in xcode 9 for old here map SDK, But when I download here map new SDK which is v3.10 and try to upload build to iTunes with xcode 10, this scrip was not working. Please let me know what should I do. Error was generated please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684751/upload-build-to-itunes-error-from-xcode-10-1

Answer (score 1):

I try with .sh script and this is working for me.

Please follow below steps

1. Unzip.tar file (i.e HERE_Premium_iOS_SDK_v3.7.0.118.tar)
2. Open extracted folder 'HERESDK-Premium'. ('HERESDK-Premium' folder generated when you extract 'HERE_Premium_iOS_SDK_v3.7.0.118.tar' file)
3. Open terminal
4. Go to extracted folder path ('HERESDK-Premium->framework' you can found 'strip_sim.sh' file in this folder and **NMAKit.framework**)
5. Run scrip in terminal with this command `sh strip_sim.sh` and press enter. (**NMAKit.framework** will be modified with this script).
6. Wait for complete process.
7. Copy new modify framework in your project and try to submit your build.

> Note : When you run `sh strip_sim.sh` script your **NMAKit.framework** will be modified. Make sure replace new framework to old framework after uploading your build to iTunes.

**New framework is not running in simulator.**