# Upload build to itunes error from xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, here-api

I try to validate build / upload build to iTunes the error was occurred.

*Note : I am using custom framework and developed in `Objective-c` language.*

**Review ipa content**

This is screenshot of custom framework summary, please check warning inside the screenshot.

> **Warning text of review ipa content (Custom framework)**
>
> macOS High Sierra is the last version of macOS that will run 32-bit
>   apps without compromise. The Mac App Store will require all apps
>   (including updates) to be exclusively 64-bit by June 2018.
>   [image]

**Error**
[image]
I am also write script in Project->Target->Build Phase->Run Script

both scrip are same, I just shared both link for your reference.

**Script link**

Link 1 : [Unable to submit archive including Here Maps Premium SDK with Xcode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276824/unable-to-submit-archive-including-here-maps-premium-sdk-with-xcode-8-2-1)

Link 2 : http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

This project was uploaded from xcode 9.4 but when I update my custom framework the error was occurred.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It took me days to figure out the correct run script for Xcode 10. But I have it now and it works fine. Here it is :

```
######################

# Options

######################




REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=false




FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"




SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"




DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"




UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"




FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"







######################

# Build Frameworks

######################




xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1




xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1




######################

# Create directory for universal

######################




rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"




mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"




mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"







######################

# Copy files Framework

######################




cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"







######################

# Make an universal binary

######################




lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo




# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework

if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then

cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo

fi



if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then

cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo

fi




######################

# On Release, copy the result to release directory

######################

OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"




rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"

mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"




cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"




if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then

open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"

fi
```

The only thing I had to do is to create a new project for my custom framework on Xcode 10 and copy all files from Xcode 9 project and recompile it again. Directly recompiling Xcode 9 project on Xcode 10 didn't work somehow.

Comment: hello, nitish this scrip was not working for me, any other way to remove this error ?