# HERE API iOS Integration: missing required architecture x86_64

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to integrate the HERE API (via manual framework import - we don't use pods) into our current project, but am getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ./NMAKit.framework/NMAKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NMAApplicationContext", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Been over the user's guide as well as the readme files, but don't see anything that helps to resolve this issue.

Is it just that the framework doesn't support that arch?  Or did I miss a setting, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both HERE iOS SDKs (HERE iOS SDK Premium Edition v3.11 and HERE iOS SDK Starter Edition v3.11) have x86_64 architecture.

I assume that you have executed the [simulator architecture stripping script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276824/unable-to-submit-archive-including-here-maps-premium-sdk-with-xcode-8-2-1), which is used for application publishing.
You can check available architectures using `lipo` command in Terminal:

```
$ lipo -info YOUR_PROJECT_LOCATION/NMAKit.framework/NMAKit 
Architectures in the fat file: NMAKit are: x86_64 i386 armv7 arm64
```

If you don't have all architectures please download the HERE iOS SDK:

- OPTION A) from https://developer.here.com using your HERE account;
- OPTION B) using CocoaPods ([HERE Starter SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/HEREMapsStarter) OR [HERE Premium SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/HEREMaps))

**NOTE**: I recommend you to use the real device for product development and validation. You can use the simulator (x86_64 architecture) for a general development, but it has a lot of differences with real device (at least in iOS API support, hardware, display differences). More details about differences can be found at [Apple Simulator Overview documentation](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d).

Comment: Thanks!  I re-downloaded a new copy of the framework (don't use pods) and commented out that script.  The app builds fine now.   Regarding simulator use, it is much slower to constantly build for a real device, despite the minor differences.  We test and validate across the family of real devices, but for day to day dev work, the simulator is much more feasible.